# Visual Studio Debug New Instance Stops Working in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-debugging

This weird thing has happened to me twice now.  I already have an instance of the debug running.  I'll either hit F5, click Enter in the address bar, or somehow refresh the page and out of nowhere, I get "This webpage is not available".  It will still work in FF and IE.  I can refresh those pages using the same localhost URL and ports without issue.  I closed Visual Studio and started a new instance of debug, still doesn't work.  Last time it happened to me, it just randomly started working a while later.

**UPDATE**

I started debugging in FF and happened to check back at Chrome and it started working again.  It would still be nice to know the cause and solution.